# passing argument 1 from incompatible pointer type

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

**Why does this code...:**

```
NSDictionary *testDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kABOtherLabel, @"other", kABWorkLabel, @"work", nil];
// There are 9 more key-value pairs that i've omitted here.
```

**throw this warning:**
`warning: passing argument 1 of 'dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys' from incompatible pointer type`

Incidentally, the code works as expected, but I don't like leaving warnings un-delt-with.  I assume it doesn't like that I'm storing a constant in a dictionary.  Well, where can I store it then?  Should I just place `(void *)` before every constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the iPhone, `kABOtherLabel` is a `CFStringRef` and not an `NSString *`. However, the two are toll-free bridged, so you can just cast it to `NSString *`:

```
NSDictionary *testDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(NSString *)kABOtherLabel, @"other", (NSString *)kABWorkLabel, @"work", nil];
```

(Also, you may have your keys and values reversed in this call, unless you want your literal strings to be the keys (objects come first)).

Comment: +1 Thanks.  Good plan. I noticed that I only get the warning as it relates to that first object.  Typecasting the other objects doesn't seem necessary (as it pertains to warnings, at least). I DO want my literal strings to be the keys.  It took me a minute to discover the order of things.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `kABOtherLabel` is a constant integer which is not an object. If you want to add it as an object use something along with lines of `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:kABOtherLabel]` (same goes for second value object)

Comment: I see, so it wants an object. Well, if you print `kABOtherLabel` you get a value of `_$!<Other>!$_` so I don't think it's an integer, it's a `CFTypeRef`. BUT it sounds like you're right that it's not an object and that's what `NSDictionary` is looking for.  I wonder what the right way is to store a list of String > Constant pairs?

Comment: Well regarding the printing you can print with %d placeholder which will show you integer representation of that constant. Other than that - you can store string > constant pairs in old-school struct.

Comment: +1 Oh, I like that.  Maybe I'll make a dictionary of string > integer pairs.